# How to recover deleted nodes and relationships in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I accidentally deleted all nodes and relationships in my graph db. Is there a way I can cancel the last run query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not, unless you have a backup.